# split string based on a symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to split a string into an array based on the second occurrence of the symbol `_`

```
var string = "this_is_my_string";
```

I want to split the string after the second underscore. The string is not always the same but it always has 2 or more underscores in it. I always need it split on the second underscore.

In the example string above I would need it to be split like this.

```
var split = [this_is, _my_string];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var string = "this_is_my_string";
var firstUnderscore = string.indexOf('_');
var secondUnderscore = string.indexOf('_', firstUnderscore + 1);
var split = [string.substring(0, secondUnderscore),
             string.substring(secondUnderscore)];
```

Paste it into your browser's console to try it out. No need for a jsFiddle.

Comment: This would only work for their example, what about a solution to a longer string e.g. `a_b_c_d_e_f = [a_b, c_d, e_f]`

Comment: In fact, it is clear that it isn't: "The string is not always the same but it always has **2 or more underscores** in it. I always need it split on the **second** underscore."

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "this_is_my_string";

var matches = str.match(/(.*?_.*?)(_.*)/); // MAGIC HAPPENS HERE

var firstPart = matches[1];  // this_is
var secondPart = matches[2]; // _my_string
```

This uses [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) to find the first two underscores, and captures the part up to it and the part after it. The first subexpression, `(.*?_.*?)`, says "any number of characters, an underscore, and again any number of characters, keeping the number of characters matched as small as possible, and capture it". The second one, `(_.*)` means "match an underscore, then any number of characters, as much of them as possible, and capture it". The result of the `match` function is an array starting with the full matched region, followed by the two captured groups.

Comment: For a website that seeks to explain programming problems to people, "MAGIC HAPPENS HERE" isn't helpful...

Comment: You're right, badly worded. It wasn't to obscure, just to point out the line that is the actual answer, the rest is fluff. I will expand on what it actually does.

Answer (score 2):

```
var string = "this_is_my_string"; 
var splitChar = string.indexOf('_', string.indexOf('_') + 1);

var result = [string.substring(0, splitChar),
string.substring(splitChar, string.length)];
```

This should work.

Comment: This is exactly equivalent to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8527352/139010).

Comment: You are right, I didn't noticed you already posted it. Good work!

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is quite old... but couldn't help but notice that no one provided a working solution. Here's one that works:

```
    String str = "this_is_my_string";
    String undScore1 = str.split("_")[0];
    String undScore2 = str.split("_")[1];
    String bothUndScores = undScore1 + "_" + undScore2 + "_";
    String allElse = str.split(bothUndScores)[1];
    System.out.println(allElse);
```

This is assuming you know there will always be at least 2 underscores - "allElse" returns everything after the second occurrence.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Nice answer!